How to force NuGet package manager to create packages.config file while installing the packages?
I am working on a windows forms based .Net project having some old projects targeting .Net4.8 and some new projects targeting .Net8.0.
I have been asked to maintain NuGet packages in Packages.config for every project.
For projects with .Net4.8, I was able to do it by setting Default package management format to 'packages.config'. However, for the projects based on new .Net8.0, this is not working.
I tried various solutions including those mentioned here:
Switch back to packages.config - clarification on answer
Addionally, I tried this solution as well:
How do I get NuGet to install/update all the packages in the packages.config? which failed with an error: '-Reinsatll' parameter does not apply to PackageReference based projects.
Is there a working solution to force the NuGet package manager to install/update the packages using packages.config? Or can we change some configuration for PackageReference based projects to achieve this?
Note: Newer projects targeting .Net8 include the rest APIs which are called from the older projects and we do not have the migration backup files for the solution.

.NET (core) no longer supports packages.config. You can only use PackageReference.

If you want to maintain nuget packages in packages.config for every project, you can manually create packages.config file to the project file and remove all  PackageReference elements out of .csproj file.

If you want to maintain NuGet packages in Packages.config for some new projects targeting .Net8.0, i think it is impossible to force Nuget Package Manager to create Packages.config file, because automatically migrating projects from PackageReference -> packages.config is not something that will be supported.
But here is a workaround, you can check the followings:
1.Add an empty packages.config file to the project root. You can copy demo from packages.config reference
2.Unload the project or close vs and open the csproj file in a text editor.
3.Remove all PackageReference elements out of the project file and make sure that is not set in the project file.
4.Reload the project and make sure it can be loaded successfully.
5.Edit your packages.config file and add  all your dependencies you need like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="newtonsoft.json" version="9.0.1"  />
</packages>

6.Execute the following command
nuget install  packages.config -OutputDirectory Packages

After installing these packages, you will see packages installed to your Packages folder. Then you can maintain packages with Packages.config file.
Hope it can help you.
